# Slicing numpy array with closed path

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path

w, h = 300, 200

mask = np.zeros((h, w))

verts = [(0, h), (w/2, 0), (w, h), (0, h)]
codes = [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.CLOSEPOLY]

path = Path(verts, codes)

mask[path.contains_points(mask)] = 1
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    mask[path.contains_points(mask)] = 1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 488, in contains_points
    result = _path.points_in_path(points, radius, self, transform)
TypeError: Argument 0 to points_in_path must be an Nx2 numpy array
```

So [`matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points) does not expand array indexes which would be useful for mask creation.

How to mask numpy array with closed path (with matplotlib or without it if it's possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `path.contains_points` expects to receive an array of coordinates (Nx2 array). Then it returns a vector with N points with `True` or `False` for each point.

So, you need to create an array of coordinates (e.g. [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2] ...]) for the area you want to search through. Then you can feed it to `contains_points` to know which of the points are within the path.

There are several ways of accomplishing this, for example:

```
coordinates = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(w), np.arange(h))).reshape(-1,2)
within = coordinates[path.contains_points(coordinates)]
mask = np.zeros((h,w))
mask[within[:,1], within[:,0]] = 1
```

Now you should have an array with size h x w and 1's inside the mask.

Btw, the use of `matplotlib.path` is a nice trick!

Comment: Thanks for your observation, but perhaps you should have posted your reply as a comment instead.

Comment: @theta: I agree. Is it now more answerish than commentish?